# How do i read MongoDB data to use in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

First of all, i'm using create-react-app, and i just found out it's apparently becoming obsolete

I've been looking for hours, i found tutorials on mongoose, and all sorts of things.

So, **basically**, i have a mongoDB collection with data i want to display in my React App (which is a pretty simple App), should i set up express, mongoose, cors, or is there a more straightforward way? Is it best to use mongoDB's "data API"? or should i straight up not use mongoDB?

The downside of making the app with create-react-app is that i didn't really use nodeJS, and pretty much every solution is related to node in some way..

If you have any help, i would appreciate it, Thanks in advance!

I tried using express, mongoose, cors, mongoDB's data API, axios, but i had problems with it as i couldn't decide which option is the best

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to MongoDB directly from “React” without creating a backend server.

To connect to MongoDB from React, you will need to create a server (say Node.js server) that will act as an intermediary between React and MongoDB.

Please follow the steps in below doc,

`https://medium.com/@kaklotarrahul79/step-by-step-guide-connecting-mongodb-with-react-js-for-seamless-full-stack-development-db51c34da282`

However, you can consider Next.js 9 as a React framework that includes a built-in server that can be used to connect to MongoDB. This means that you don’t need to create a separate Node.js server for your application. You can refer to this tutorial - How to Integrate MongoDB Into Your Next.js App | MongoDB 133 to learn more.